getting 403 forbbiden error for linkedIN oauth 2.0
My react code
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

function App() {
  const [profile, setProfile] = useState(null);

  const handleLogin = () => {
    // Redirect to LinkedIn login
    window.location.href = 'http://localhost:5000/auth/linkedin';
  };

  // Fetch user profile from backend after successful login
  const fetchProfile = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/auth/user'); // This will now fetch the profile
      setProfile(response.data.user);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching profile', error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch the profile when the component mounts
    fetchProfile();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="container mt-5">
      <h1 className="text-center">LinkedIn Login Demo</h1>
      {!profile ? (
        <div className="d-flex justify-content-center">
          <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={handleLogin}>Login with LinkedIn</button>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div className="profile mt-5">
          <h3>Profile Details:</h3>
          <p><strong>Name:</strong> {profile.firstName} {profile.lastName}</p>
          <p><strong>Email:</strong> {profile.email}</p>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

my node js server code:
const express = require('express');
const passport = require('passport');
const LinkedInStrategy = require('passport-linkedin-oauth2').Strategy;
const axios = require('axios');

const router = express.Router();

// LinkedIn App Credentials
const LINKEDIN_CLIENT_ID = 'weqe'; // Replace with your actual Client ID
const LINKEDIN_CLIENT_SECRET = 'eqwe'; // Replace with your actual Client Secret
const CALLBACK_URL = 'http://localhost:5000/auth/linkedin/callback';

// Configure passport to use LinkedIn Strategy
passport.use(new LinkedInStrategy({
    clientID: LINKEDIN_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: LINKEDIN_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: CALLBACK_URL,
    scope: ['openid', 'profile', 'email','w_member_social'], // Updated scopes
    state: true,  
    passReqToCallback: true // This ensures the callback gets the request object
  },
  async function(req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    try {
      // Fetching user profile from LinkedIn API manually
      const profileResponse = await axios.get('https://api.linkedin.com/v2/userinfo', {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        },
      });
  
      // Fetching user email address
      const emailResponse = await axios.get('https://api.linkedin.com/v2/emailAddress?q=members&projection=(elements*(handle~))', {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        },
      });

      const userProfile = {
        id: profileResponse.data.id,
        firstName: profileResponse.data.localizedFirstName,
        lastName: profileResponse.data.localizedLastName,
        email: emailResponse.data.elements[0]['handle~'].emailAddress
      };

      // Pass the profile data and token to the callback
      return done(null, { profile: userProfile, token: accessToken });

    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching profile or email from LinkedIn:', error.message);
      return done(error);
    }
  }
));

// Serialize and Deserialize user
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser((obj, done) => {
  done(null, obj);
});

// LinkedIn login route
router.get('/linkedin', passport.authenticate('linkedin'));

// Callback route after LinkedIn login
router.get('/linkedin/callback', passport.authenticate('linkedin', {
  failureRedirect: '/login',
  session: false,
}), (req, res) => {
  // Send user profile and token as response
  res.json({
    message: 'Successfully logged in with LinkedIn',
    user: req.user.profile,
    token: req.user.token
  });
});

// Add the /auth/user route to send user profile to frontend
router.get('/user', (req, res) => {
  if (req.user) {
    res.json({
      user: req.user.profile,
    });
  } else {
    res.status(401).send('Unauthorized');
  }
});

module.exports = router;

my node package.json file
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.7.7",
    "express": "^4.20.0",
    "express-session": "^1.18.0",
    "nodemon": "^3.1.4",
    "passport": "^0.7.0",
    "passport-linkedin-oauth2": "github:auth0/passport-linkedin-oauth2#v3.0.0"
  }

i have written code some from chatgpt and some from stack overflow. 
At first i was facing issue of not fetching user profile.
after updating passport-linkedin-oauth2 package now im getting this error
AxiosError: Request failed with status code 403
    

I think there some issue on LinkedIn side may be I'm wrong because for the error which I was getting previously I made changes in the package version.
Kindly help out to find exactly what the issue is.
I'm new to this social login. I'm first starting with the LinkedIn as I have to start my project with this step

Did you get the access token successfully?
